# The average degree in a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I was solving the following problem from "A First Course in Network Science" by Menczer, Fortunato & Davis.
(p110, Problem 1.25)

> Netflix keeps data on customer preferences using a big bipartite
> network connecting users to titles they have watched and/or rated.
> Netflix’s movie library contains approximately 100,000 titles if you
> count streaming and DVD-by-mail. In the fourth quarter of 2013,
> Netflix reported having about 33 million users. Assume the average
> user’s degree in this network is 1000. Approximately how many links
> are in this network?

**My attempt**
Let $m=$ # of edges and $n=$# of nodes $=33\times 10^6$. The average degree of the undirected graph is $\frac{2m}{n}$. Therefore we obtain
$\frac{2m}{n} = 1000$.
Thus, we obtain $m = 500\times n = 500\times 33\times 10^6 = 1.65\times 10^{10}$.

**The Solution from Solution Manual**(Found [here](https://github.com/CambridgeUniversityPress/FirstCourseNetworkScience/blob/master/sample/Selected_Exercise_Solutions.pdf))

> Let us use the subscripts $u$ and $m$ for users and movies,
> respectively. $L = N_{u}\langle k_u\rangle =33\times 10^9$.

---

As you can see, my solution is wrong. I am not sure what went wrong with my calculation.
My guess is that we are supposed to think that the graph is directed (instead of undirected) since the average degree for a directed graph is $\frac{m}{n}$, and everything goes well with this formula. However, I am not sure how we know that we have to use a directed graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average *user's* degree, not average degree.  So the number of links is $33 \times 10^6 \times 1000 = 33 \times 10^9$.